# Problema com o plugin notify

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou com um probleminha em visualizar a notificação do plugin quando o formulario é executado. O formulario em si ta perfeito.
Oque eu percebo é que quando ele vai aparecer não da tempo e a notificação encerra antes mesmo de abrir.
Agradeço muito pela ajuda.
https://notifyjs.jpillora.com (Plugin da notificação)

FORM

```
 <form method="post" name="formCadastro" id="formCadastro" action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" onsubmit="return confirmacao();">.....</form>
```

Javascript

```
 function confirmacao() {
   $.notify("Hello World");
return true;    
}
```

Comment: Vc quer que a notificação apareça antes de enviar o formulário?

Comment: depois que enviar o formulario.

Comment: Sei. Mas depois que vc envia o formulário a página é recarregada ou está usando Ajax?

Comment: Obrigado por estar ajudando. a pagina é recarregada.

Comment: Então. Quando você submete um formulário, a página é imediatamente recarregada, não dá tempo de ver nada... o que vc deveria fazer é mostrar a mensagem APÓS a página ser recarregada informando ao usuário que tudo deu certo, ou seja, o formulário foi devidamente recebido.

Comment: perfeito. tem alguma ideia pra chegar nisso?

Comment: Sim. Após o envio a página será recarregada. Dentro do bloco no código PHP onde tudo "deu certo", vc pode chamar a função que mostra a notificação.

Comment: Não precisa desse onsubmit... vc vai chamar a função só se deu tudo certo após o envio e recarregamento da página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que quando você submete o formulário, a página é imediatamente redirecionada para o destino informado no `action`. Com isso, *não dá tempo* de mostrar nenhuma mensagem na tela (mesmo que você tente mostrar, o usuário não vai conseguir ver).

O que você deve fazer é notificar após o envio quando a página for carregada (ou recarregada, se o destino for a própria página).

A estrutura seria esta:

```
<?php
// recebo o formulário
// abro a validação do formulário (um if)
   // se deu tudo certo, chamo o plugin
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.notify("Formulário enviado com sucesso!");
});
</script>
<?php
// fecho a validação do formulário (fecha o if)
?>
```

Você também pode mostrar uma notificação de erro caso tenha havido algum problema na validação do formulário. Basta fazer um `else` e chamar o `script` da mesma forma.

Comment: pow cara. bem esclarecedor. muito obrigado. deu certo!

Answer (score -1):

Olha só pessoal, fiz algumas modificações e o notify funciona no ionic e dispara com um determinado horário.

Passo aqui para compartilhar com vocês.

arquivo index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title>Angular Notify Demo</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="angular-notify.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">

        <div>

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2>angular-notify</h2>
                        <p class="lead">Notify - angular - ionic.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <ion-content>
                <br>
                Hora: {{currentTime}}
                <br>
            </ion-content>


        </div>

       <script src="angular.js"></script>
       <script src="angular-notify.js"></script>
       <script src="demo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

demo.js

```
angular.module('app', ['cgNotify']);

    angular.module('app').controller('DemoCtrl',function($interval,$scope,notify,dateFilter) {
        $scope.currentTime = dateFilter(new Date(), 'hh:mm');

        $scope.updateTime = $interval(function() {

            $scope.currentTime = dateFilter(new Date(), 'hh:mm');
            $scope.horaAtual = dateFilter(new Date(), 'hh');
            $scope.minutosAtual = dateFilter(new Date(), 'mm');
            $scope.SegundosAtual = dateFilter(new Date(), 'ss');



            if($scope.minutosAtual == 46 && $scope.SegundosAtual == 0) {

                function demoMessageTemplate() {

                    var messageTemplate = '<span>Agora tudo deu certo!</span> ';

                    notify({
                        messageTemplate: messageTemplate,
                        classes: $scope.classes,
                        scope:$scope,
                        templateUrl: $scope.template,
                        position: $scope.position,
                    });       

                };  // fim demoMessageTemplate

                window.load = demoMessageTemplate();

            } // fim if

        }, 1000); // fim do relogio

    });
```

Aqui está todo projeto

https://github.com/fredtavares2018/notify---angular---ionic